# Python3 Convert bytes object to int

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, int

I have a bytes objects that I received from a socket and I want to extract the integer value it contains.

Looks like this

```
input = b'1         \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I tried

```
tmp_str = input.decode('ascii').strip()
int(tmp_str)
```

The error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1         \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

However, the type of `tmp_str` is `'str'`, but the length is `20`.. Looks like the object is not changed, but just some representations of it has changed..

```
>>> print(tmp_str)
1
>>> len (tmp_str)
20
>>> type(tmp_str)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(input)
<class 'bytes'>
```

How can I extract the int from this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.strip()` and `bytes.strip()` will not remove NUL bytes unless you tell them to explictly, as NUL bytes are not whitespace.

You don't have to decode the bytes to `str`, however, as `int()` can accept `bytes` objects directly. Just call `bytes.strip()` and tell it to remove both spaces and NUL:

```
int(input.strip(b' \x00')
```

Demo:

```
>>> input = b'1         \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> int(input.strip(b' \x00'))
1
```